# Purple screen with no Ubuntu logo for 1 minute before login screen appears

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, lenovo

I’ve recently upgraded  Ubuntu from 16.10 to 18.04.02.

The problem I’ve encountered is that when I boot Ubuntu, I temporarily get stuck on an all-purple screen with no Ubuntu logo for  around 1 minute before the Ubuntu logo appears. I don't actually understand why this screen is appearing.
I have even tried to press <kbd>F2</kbd> when it boots into the purple screen but in vain it shows nothing no error messages the purple screen still persists.

I have already installed latest NVIDIA drivers.

I have even tired adding `nomodeset` at the end of the `quiet splash` line in the grub file but doing that  it shows error and doesn't even reaches log in screen.

I have even tried adding `noresume` in the `quiet splash` line but still it doesn't solve the issue.

I don't know about LVM. But if there is an issue with LVM then the kernel should be slow but I think my kernel works completely fine.

I have Nvedia-MX150 graphics with 8gb ram and I have intel-i5 8th generation and 1 TB HDD.The time taken by my laptop to boot up is around 2min.

Now I feel completely hopeless I don't even have any idea what to do.

After I type the command `systemd-analyze blame` on the command line, it shows:

```
 43.161s systemd-journal-flush.service
 42.584s dev-sda2.device
 40.467s apt-daily.service
 37.124s ufw.service
 34.269s systemd-sysctl.service
 33.841s systemd-udevd.service
 31.885s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-91.mount
 30.862s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
 30.199s snap-ddgr-325.mount
 28.341s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
 26.429s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
 25.531s snap-evince-111.mount
 23.274s snap-core18-1055.mount
  8.707s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-59.mount
  7.277s plymouth-quit-wait.service
  5.729s plymouth-start.service
  5.083s bolt.service
  4.575s snapd.service
  3.779s gpu-manager.service
  3.406s networkd-dispatcher.service
  2.732s plymouth-read-write.service
  2.571s apt-daily-upgrade.service
  2.554s apparmor.service
  2.400s NetworkManager.service
  2.286s udisks2.service
  2.274s accounts-daemon.service
  2.196s dev-loop7.device
  2.160s grub-common.service
  1.945s preload.service
  1.928s motd-news.service
  1.672s ModemManager.service
  1.641s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-88.mount
  1.608s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  1.581s apport-autoreport.service
  1.549s dev-loop12.device
  1.536s dev-loop4.device
  1.536s dev-loop5.device
  1.536s dev-loop2.device
  1.534s dev-loop1.device
  1.324s systemd-modules-load.service
  1.234s keyboard-setup.service
  1.214s avahi-daemon.service
  1.136s dev-loop16.device
  1.101s fwupd.service
   873ms swapfile.swap
   636ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   618ms systemd-random-seed.service
   616ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-90.mount
   615ms wpa_supplicant.service
   602ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7CB3\x2d3F04.service
   599ms systemd-journald.service
   585ms snap-qalculate-133.mount
   585ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
   573ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   572ms snap-core18-1066.mount
   523ms rsyslog.service
   519ms snap-core-7169.mount
   510ms tlp.service
   506ms colord.service
   465ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-288.mount
   464ms polkit.service
   442ms dev-loop6.device
   380ms binfmt-support.service
   355ms snapd.seeded.service
   344ms dns-clean.service
   304ms gdm.service
   282ms systemd-logind.service
   274ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   255ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   219ms nvidia-persistenced.service
   202ms upower.service
   192ms thermald.service
   185ms user@121.service
   176ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   165ms systemd-resolved.service
   152ms snap-evince-101.mount
   143ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   132ms networking.service
   129ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   128ms dev-mqueue.mount
   127ms dev-hugepages.mount
   108ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
    90ms bluetooth.service
    81ms speech-dispatcher.service
    79ms dev-loop14.device
    70ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
    70ms rng-tools.service
    69ms pppd-dns.service
    67ms snap-ubuntu\x2dmake-526.mount
    63ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dcore18-29.mount
    62ms user@1000.service
    60ms systemd-update-utmp.service
    48ms snap-core-7270.mount
    46ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
    39ms packagekit.service
    39ms snapd.socket
    34ms apport.service
    32ms setvtrgb.service
    29ms dev-loop17.device
    29ms dev-loop11.device
    29ms dev-loop15.device
    28ms dev-loop13.device
    28ms dev-loop10.device
    28ms dev-loop8.device
    28ms dev-loop9.device
    26ms dev-loop3.device
    26ms dev-loop0.device
    21ms boot-efi.mount
    20ms dev-loop18.device
    18ms alsa-restore.service
     9ms rtkit-daemon.service
     9ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
     8ms kerneloops.service
     7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     6ms systemd-user-sessions.service
     6ms ureadahead-stop.service
     5ms dev-loop19.device
     2ms dev-loop21.device
     2ms console-setup.service
     2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     1ms dev-loop20.device
     1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

But the problem is that the time period of these services keep on changing on every time I boot.

Comment: Look at  the results of `systemd-analyze blame` from command line. That is the go-to command to see what service takes what time to boot. Evaluate the top services and decide if you can disable them. If needed post the results into the question and we can provide disable commands for services.

Comment: In your BIOS, is your HDD set to operate in IDE mode or AHCI mode? If it's in IDE mode, it will make disk access much slower, which can cause what you're seeing (it seems most of your slowness is related to disk activities).

Answer (score 0):

Removing obsolete packages using Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) -> *Installed (local or obsolete)* in the left pane may fix this problem. If obsolete packages are causing Ubuntu to hang when booting, removing obsolete packages permanently will change it from always hanging when booting to never hanging when booting.

Before you remove an obsolete package in Synaptic run the following command on the package name to check if any other packages that you have installed require it as a dependency.

```
apt-cache rdepends <package-name>
```

Replace `<package-name>` in the above command with the name of the package.

Comment: But I see a lot of risk while doing this,I think this may even make my problem worse.

Comment: I'm self-confident because I check everything thoroughly before I remove any packages. Consider this: the worst thing that can happen if you do nothing is that you'll have to live with a longer than usual boot time. That's not much of an inconvenience.